# No mouse-scrolling in Pane objects?

Tags: user-interface, wolfram-mathematica

The following `Pane` object does not scroll when the mouse wheel is used. Does anyone experience the same behaviour? Is it the default behaviour? Any idea why? Could it be platform-specific?

```
CreateDialog[Pane[Column[Range[30]], {300, 200}, Scrollbars -> True]]
```

My platform: Win7-64, Mathematica 8.0.1

Comment: I experience the same behaviour on Windows Vista. What platform are you using?

Comment: Same here on Win7-64. Tried everything I could come with to no avail.

Comment: Same problem with OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: Not a bug. It just hasn't been designed to operate that way according to a tech support reply I got some months ago.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution:

```
Needs["GUIKit`"]
ref = GUIRun[
   Widget["Panel", {
     Widget["ScrollPane", {
       "viewportView" -> Widget["List", {
          "visibleRowCount" -> 4,
          "items" -> Script[Range[30]]
          }] }] }]
   ];
```

The problem with Pane is that the `MouseWheel` event is not bound, as it is in GUIKit. Using this technique you could also do `Bind["MouseWheel" ...]` to any other action.

Comment: Interestingly, ctrl-scroll wheel works to enlarge en shrink the window. So it receives scroll wheel events, but that may be at window level and not at pane level.

Comment: @Sjoerd AFAIK, the bound events are those listed under "more info" in reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EventHandler.html. I may be wrong, of course :)

Comment: GUIKit` indeed works, though I would rather solve this with basic Mathematica functions, if possible.
@belisarius: It is stated there: "...event specifications include...", which *might* indicate that there are other unlisted events. Has anyone found "MouseWheel" or any similar? I myself have failed. How does GUIKit solve this?

Comment: I have queried the use of the word "include" a few times with tech support and each time I have been told that the stuff being referenced is the complete documented stuff available. "include" just seems to be their way of phrasing but should be taken to mean that you can use one of the following listed options.